# Powershell - Import seperate array values to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, import

I'm very new to Powershell, and I'm trying to extract data from Teams (using the Graph API )  I have successfully exported the required data into an SQL table (using the Invoke-Sqlcmd function )

When extracting the users involved on the call, I get the CallID but the participant values are placed in a single field

```
CallID                               Participants
CallGUID-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx   John Smith Mary Brown Billy Dee Williams
```

and I need to format it like below

```
CallID                               Participants
CallGUID-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx   John Smith
CallGUID-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx   Mary Brown
CallGUID-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx   Billy Dee Williams
```

The code I am using is below.

```
    $clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $clientSecret = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $tenantName = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $tenantName = "xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    $resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
    
    $tokenBody = @{  
        Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"  
        Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  
        Client_Id     = $clientId  
        Client_Secret = $clientSecret  
    }
    
    $URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/CallGUID-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    
    $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenBody
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($tokenResponse.access_token)"} -Uri $URL
    
    $CallDetailsID = $response.id
    $CallDetailsStart = $response.startDateTime
    $CallDetailsEnd = $response.endDateTime
    $CallDetailsParticipants = $response.Participants.user.displayname
    
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "INSERT INTO [Alpha].[dbo].[Table] (CallID, Participants) SELECT '$CallGUID',  $CallDetailsParticipants)" -ServerInstance "Server\Instance"
```

Is anyone able to help point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to loop over each participant to insert them individually.

Try

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO [Alpha].[dbo].[Table] (CallID, Participants) SELECT '$CallGUID', '{0}'"
foreach ($participant in $CallDetailsParticipants) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ($qry -f $participant) -ServerInstance "Server\Instance"
}
```

(edited by OP after testing)

Comment: Hi Theo,

I'm getting an error on line 13

Invoke-Sqlcmd : Use of key 'failover partner' requires the key 'initial catalog' to be present.
At line:56 char:13
+             Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $qry -f $participant -ServerInstance ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (Server\Instance:PSObject) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Comment: ALSO This error

At line:56 char:42
+             Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $qry -f $participant -ServerInstance ...
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
 
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FailoverPartner'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I made a copy-paste error while posting this.. Should be fixed now.

Comment: I've got it working with your help. I had another error, which I fixed by removing the extra closing bracket and putting quotes around the {0} My $qry line looks like this 

$qry = "INSERT INTO [Alpha].[dbo].[Table] (CallID, Participants) SELECT '$CallDetailsID', '{0}'"

foreach ($participant in $CallDetailsParticipants) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ($qry -f $participant) -ServerInstance "Server\Instance"
}


I hope you don't mind, but I updated your post for others / my reference in future
Thanks very much for your assistance!

Comment: @Rob Good job! I don't mind at all. As said, I couldn't test this myself, so I'm glad you did that.